# MongoDB mlab connectivity in Android

Tags: android, mongodb, android-studio, android-asynctask, mlab

I am very new in android. Creating a new app to connect the android application with MongoDB (mlab.com). I have successfully connected with Java. But in android, I am not getting how to do it. I have checked without AsyncTask but also getting the same error Can anyone help!

Here is my code

```
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.MongoClientException;
import com.mongodb.MongoClientURI;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
import org.bson.Document;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    EditText et1,et2,et3;
    Button b1;
    MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI("mongodb://user:malak@ds149309.mlab.com:49309/mydb");

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    et1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameText);
    et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailText);
    et3 =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.mobText);
    b1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String name = et1.getText().toString();
            String email = et2.getText().toString();
            String mob = et3.getText().toString();
            InsertData(name,email);
        }
    });
}
public void InsertData(final String name, final String email) {

    class SendPostReqAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(uri);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Coonected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("aghori");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Dtabase connected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("sampleCollection");


                // collection.insertOne(document);


            } catch (MongoClientException e) {

            }
            return "Data Inserted Successfully";
        }

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.CUPCAKE)
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            super.onPostExecute(result);

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data Submit Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }

    SendPostReqAsyncTask sendPostReqAsyncTask = new SendPostReqAsyncTask();

    sendPostReqAsyncTask.execute(name, email);
}
```

}

When I run this application and click the button to submit it automatically gets stopped. Hvae anyone any idea please help.

Comment: Don't do that. Your mobile application has no business talking directly to a database. What you want is an "intermediary" API, which sits between your client and the database itself. MLab offers a REST API, and there are also other solutions out there. But don't even attempt using the Java client directly from your Android application.

Comment: Thank you. But is it possible to connect MLab in this process?

Comment: It really should not be. In that way more of you who suddenly decide to add an external database to your app would get the message. Just don't do it. Do some reading and find many other sources telling you the exact same thing.